# How to print out all attributes of an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm using D3 and when I hover on a node I want a text box to appear with all the nodes attributes written to it. I have made a text box and im able to write attributes i know to that text box :

```
function onHover(){
    d3.selectAll("#nodeAttributes")
            .text(function() { return (d.type); }) //random attribute i know            
            ;
}
```

This is called on 'mouseover' on the node. But what if I dont know what attributes a node has ? How can I loop through all attributes and write all of them to the text box. My data looks similar to this :

```
nodes: [
        {
          "type": "o",
          "name": "fred",
          "age": "16",
          "class": "maths",
.
.
.
.

        },
```

What I want the outputted text to look like :

```
type: o
name: fred
age: 16
class: maths
```

I'm unsure how loop through each attribute of that chosen node (d)

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about console.log()?

Comment: i know how to write the text its just i want it so i can pass it different data and always print that data out. That way i dont have to specifically code what the output it, its variable

Comment: sorry @sgtBOSE i dont understand what youre saying ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate in your object with the following code :

```
function onHover() {
  d3.selectAll('#nodeAttributes').html(function (d) {
    var str = '';
    for (var key in d) {
      str += key + ': ' + d[key] + '<br/>'
    }
    return str;
  }
  );
}
```

Comment: the break doesnt seem to work but i can fix that. All works great, appreciate the quick response :D thank you

Comment: You should replace `.text` with `.html`